# map() as class member versus map() as independent function?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, kotlin, map-function

I just found out that mapping a list is in e.g. Python and Haskell is done like this:

```
newlist = map(function, somelist)
```

In e.g. Kotlin and Dart it is done like this:

```
newlist = somelist.map(function)
```

I am wondering what advantages each solution has over the other?
The Python/Haskell implementation is more "functional" isn´t it?

Comment: What renders python's `map` less functional is the iterable protocol, because it abstracts from the structure you're iterating over. In FP `map` must preserve this very structure. Iterate is just too imprecise. In FP we `fold`, `map` or `traverse`.

Comment: This question may attract opinionated answers, but informed ones. It is also pretty specific in my view. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

Python's `map` doesn't just work for lists; it works for any iterable. Rather than add separate `map` methods to disparate classes (or adding a do-nothing `map` method to `object` and overriding it multiple times), Python uses the iterable protocol; any class that implements `__iter__` (providing an object the implements `__next__`) can be used with `map`.

Comment: upvoted, but why are Kotlin and Dart different?

Comment: Because the designers made different decisions. There's no right decision here.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really have anything to do with "more functional", just one of usage.

Haskell doesn't have methods, so

```
newlist = map function somelist
```

is the only way to write it.

In Python, `map` doesn't preserve the structure of the iterable, rather it makes either a new list (Python2) or a new map object (Python3). It's just a regular function which can take any iterable object as an argument, so it's not attached to a specific object. (On a side note, `map` isn't a particularly popular function, it's considered more "pythonic" to use a list or generator comprehension).

In Kotlin, all iterables implement the method `map`. Unlike in Python where it's just a regular function, it's a regular (overridable) method, and is used as such.

The real difference here, is that in Kotlin, we can override it with a more optimised version, whilst in Python we can't. This is probably more OOP, but it's not really any less functional.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat opinion based, and my language of choice is Python, but I'll give it a shot.

Python puts a very high emphasis on duck typing, especially with the iterable and sequence protocols.

When you call `map(function, some_iterable)` it is - at least conceptually - not important what type `some_iterable` has, as long as you can pull values from it one by one in oder to apply a function to each of them. It could be a list, or a tuple, or a string, or a generator ... having a global `map` function ensures that all of these will work, even your self-written classes that are iterable by implementing `__iter__`.

In my opinion it is far more elegant to implement the iterable protocol in `YourClass`, which unlocks a whole bunch of features, rather than writing your own `YourClass.map` function or having to call `list(YourClass_instance).map(function)`.

Another example is the `str.join` method. Why do we write `"sep".join(my_list)` instead of `my_list.join(sep)`? It's again the fact that when building the resulting string, you don't really care if the values are pulled from a list, or set, or tuple, or any other iterable type. `str.join` accepts any iterable.

`len` is a builtin function for similar reasons. Sequences (and in general most containers) can expose their number of items with `len(my_container)` as long as they implement a `__len__` method, you don't have to guess whether it is `my_container.len()`, `my_container.num_items()`,  or `my_container.size()`.

[Here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/) is a relevant article to this discussion.

Comment: Yes, except that `map` in FP is structure preserving whereas map in python isn't. If all you really care about in the thing you're mapping over is what "elements" are inside of it - which is of course often enough - then this approach works fine. It's not actually at all better than something like `collection.asSequence.map`  which you can do just fine in all the other languages though. If you want a structure preserving map you're out of luck with the python approach.

Comment: @Cubic true, you would manually have to cast the return value of `map` to whatever type you want in Python (e.g. `tuple(map(func, iterable))`). Not preserving the structure of the underlying iterable works fine in Python because the language has been carefully designed such that in almost all use cases, you either *should* simply not care or the "correct" data type for further processing is an obvious choice. Thanks for your input about the FP languages, I'm underinformed with regards to these.

Comment: For dictionaries, tuples and lists this works fine, but consider non-flat structures you could map over, like a tree: `Node 1 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node 3 Empty Empty)`. Now imagine you want to add one to all the nodes - with a structure preserving map you could do that, in an iterable based map there's no way to get the tree structure back out of the iterable.

Answer (score 2):

> The Python/Haskell implementation is more "functional" isn´t it?

Not much. The Kotlin syntax lends itself less to composition, but...

Instead of composing (e.g. `(map f . map g) somelist`), you'd chain the method calls together (e.g. `somelist.map(f).map(g)`). This requires that the chained object supports `map`, so if you were to write your own list combinators, they'd have to be injected into that object. Since Kotlin supports [extension methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), you can still avoid coupling your data type and your higher-order list combinators (which is generally a drawback in object-oriented programming).

Comment: Well here it’s explained like you said (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) So .map() in kotlin is probably just an extension function? And do you know something about dart?

Comment: @TobiasMarschall: Yes, `map` is an extension method [made on `Iterable<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html). Similarly, [Dart's `map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) is made in the [`Iterable` abstract class](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/iterable.dart). For comparison, Haskell has [various type classes (`Functor`, `Traversable`, ...](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_and_Traversable). The difference is mainly in how they do [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).